# High Contrast mode for low vision users

Tags: accessibility, user-experience

1. Is it recommended to provide High Contrast Mode setting for users who visit your websites or is it okay to assume that users will use browser extensions to view pages in High Contrast Mode when needed? What are the pros and cons of both?
2. Name some of the websites that provide HCM examples.
3. Best practices to adopt while coding for HCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you follow these guidelines, there should be no need to use a
>   "high-contrast mode" and your website will still look perfectly
>   normal.

I wouldn't go that far.  There are lots of low vision users that have a hard time reading screens with white backgrounds and prefer a high contrast mode with a black background.  Most of these modes have black backgrounds and full intensity foreground colors such as yellow, cyan, purple, and white, such as this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of high contrast table containing a black background, cyan table headers, and yellow table cells]

For users that need these types of views, it's "normal" to them.  If your website provides different color theme options, kudos to you.

From a WCAG compliance perspective, @Josh is correct that 4.5:1 is the minimum contrast to achieve AA compliance.  AAA compliance requires a 7:1 ratio.

Many users are used to using the built in OS setting to get high contrast mode, but that doesn't mean your website couldn't provide one too.  If you don't provide one, then test your site that the colors work properly when using the OS high contrast.

You can see a video of high contrast options at https://www.sas.com/en_us/company-information/accessibility.html#m=video-sas-visual-analytics, at the 2:20 mark.  The video demos older software but the new version has it too.  The video shows other features that help with accessibility too.

Comment: Not sure how overlays came into this discussion. I never (and will never) recommend an overlay.  The "go that far" comment was in regards to your suggestion that high contrast isn't needed if you follow WCAG 1.4.3. That is simply not true. There will always be some users that need high contrast. www.ca.gov still has a menu that lets you toggle on high contrast. It's fantastic they they provide that. They're thinking about total usability rather than just minimum WCAG conformance. Remember that WCAG is just a minimal baseline for accessibility.

Comment: Everyone's entitled to an opinion.  If you ask the general accessibility community of professionals, you will find very few that think WCAG AA is the end-all be-all of accessibility.  The majority believe WCAG (not matter what level) is the starting point and a minimum level of support.  WCAG does not address a lot of usability issues so you could have a WCAG conformant site that is not usable and thus not accessible.

Comment: Nope, never said that.  I said if you want to create some high contrast styles and allow the user to switch to them, that's a fantastic feature.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you're free to interpret things as you want.  I'm just updating facts to make things more accessible for others.  This was an old question that you wanted to revive by adding comments recently.  You new/recent comments had questions in them so it sounded like you wanted answers.  Going back to the original answer, saying that high contrast isn't needed, is just not true.

Comment: Certainly up to you. I’m always answering questions on SO.

Comment: Here's what all of this comes down to. You have way more experience and reputation than I do. Yet, instead of helping to educate and help those junior to you in the industry, you regularly choose to create answers that discredit others. This is a giant middle finger to anyone on the other end of it, and it's entirely self-serving. It's fine to disagree, but this answer is "punching down". Maybe consider working on that.